# Tooltip not coming on bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a navbar and there is a green button. When the cursor hovers on it, I want a tooltip (at the bottom) to appear. However that is not happening. I used the following script:

```
$("[data-toggle="tooltip"]").tooltip();
```

A very strange thing happens. The tooltip is getting hidden underneath the navbar. Or so it seems. Can anybody help me with this? The following is the HTML code for the button (it is enclosed within the header tag):

```
<a id="ID" style="margin-right: 20px" class="btn btn-success" 
   data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" 
   data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom">Has hover state</a>
```

Comment: Did you try adding `z-index`? Please post your code for HTML and CSS.

Comment: There is some bad quotes in you javascript, you cannot have, that may be the issue, try `$("a[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();`

Comment: @RC. there is no change. I'm facing the same problem I'm afraid :/

Comment: @MaihanNijat no I haven't added z-index. Edit:I tried adding z-index. No change

Answer (score 1):

Fix your JavaScript quotes:

```
$("a[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/WEbUoBm0Jzo4LWMEjt3g?p=preview) as reference, it has your markup and the fixed JavaScript.

Note that the `.tooltip()` is running after the DOM is ready with the relevant markup.

---

EDIT: After a long discussion in the comments, the solution was to add this to the CSS:

```
.tooltip{ position: fixed;}
```

Comment: the problem still persists. Also, another thing: when I try the same thing in the body, the tooltip appears as it should but it's sort of hiding underneath the navbar..

Comment: What if you set the z-index higher?

Comment: I set the z-index of the navbar as 1 and that of the button as 5. No change. Should I set a higher number?

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/664sAgQn6NDXQzDyVpxf?p=preview)  Strangely enough it's working here but not on the actual page I made. Should I show you a plunker of the entire code?

Comment: @sindhugauri yeah, can you put the whole code, sometimes the higher z-index f's with the lower childs

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/664sAgQn6NDXQzDyVpxf?p=preview) here you go

Comment: @sindhugauri why does the #ID have ```position:bottom```, there is no property of position as bottom, also the ```z-index``` will work only when you apply ```position: absolute``` or ```position: relative```, check if that is working. :)

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter I made some additions to my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/664sAgQn6NDXQzDyVpxf?p=preview) and I'm back to square one. :/

Comment: @sindhugauri add to your CSS : ```.tooltip{ position: fixed;}``` its more of a band-aid solution but see if that works for you